# iPhone: What is the correct usage of viewDidDisappear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm still very new to Objective C, and I was wondering something regarding viewDidDisappear.
I have an app that plays a sound (using AVAudioPlayer), and I want to stop the sound when the view is switched.

If I do this in my view controller implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.audioPlayer stop];
}
```

it works fine. But the small programmer in my brain is saying that I'm not using this correctly.
I'm pretty sure you are supposed to CALL viewDidDisappear with a boolean argument, rather than just specify (BOOL)animated; besides, it would be nice to have some animation in my view switching... then again, that might be a whole different discussion!

So, what am I doing wrong, and how would I correctly use this? Do I have to link the call a button action? Where is the correct play to actually declare the function itself?
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I implement `viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` **EXTENSIVELY**, along with `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear` and `viewWillDisappear` The main reason to implement this method is to make your view controller to do something at the event, such as `viewDidDisappear` You don't call this method, but your app will call your view controller to do what's implemented there. Since this is inherited method, as long as you make sure all the inherited implementation from the super class can be done, it's great to implement `viewDidDisappear`. So, I suggest you to change your code to be like this:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];    // Call the super class implementation.
    // Usually calling super class implementation is done before self class implementation, but it's up to your application.

    [self.audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` is a method declaration, not a call of any sort. The method itself is called by UIKit as view controllers are manipulated; you don't need to call it yourself unless you're writing your own code that makes view controllers appear and disappear by directly manipulating the views they control (e.g. if you were rewriting UINavigationController for some reason).

You are doing something wrong, though: you must call `[super viewDidDisappear:animated]` somewhere in your implementation, or things may break.

Comment: So I guess I did understand it more or less correctly, THANKS! However, could you please elaborate on the [super viewDidDisappear:animated] call? I'm not completely clued up on the whole super business... I'm currently a coding hazard :p What would happen if I left that out?

Answer (score 4):

The "small programmer" voice in your mind is probably more used to procedural coding, where you call the OS and tell it what to do.  Cocoa Touch instead uses an event driven paradigm, where your program has routines (methods) that the OS(framework)calls when it is good and ready.  viewDidDisappear is one of those routines.  Just sit tight, and wait for the OS to call it (assuming you've set everything up properly.)

Comment: Yeah... PHP s my forte, and I must say that I'm just starting to get to grips with proper OO and the whole MVC thing. However, in this instance I actually need the app to do something when the view disappears. Would that not warrant the need to tell my view to use viewDidDisappear in order to do it?

Comment: @capitales :  Nope.  The opposite.  You don't tell the view.  When the view disappears, the OS tells you.

Comment: woah... objective c knows kung fu! I guess I kinda understand what you mean. But going by the logic, I should be able to somehow check for viewDidDisappear and the OS should respond with "yes it did", correct?

Comment: @capitales7 :  The OS sort of tells you at the time it calls viewDidDisappear, "yes it did" disappear.  You have to wait for it to tell you.  (You could set a flag when it told you.)

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidDisappear:` is an optional method that your view can utilize to execute custom code when the view does indeed disappear. You aren't required to have this in your view, and your code should (almost?) never need to call it.